# Can't upload icon for Facebook iframe app - only see a CANCEL button

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm trying to upload an icon to a new Facebook app (iframe) but the "Upload an icon" popup window only shows a CANCEL button, there's no OK or UPLOAD, or anything.

There is a little padlock icon on the top right so it seems it's locked. Any ideas? 
Can't find anything about this.

Here is what I get: 
[image]

Any ideas?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this will be pushed soon.

If you need this urgently, you can try the work-around mentioned in the comments. It's a weird one though: after doing it, it wasn't displaying in the app settings window, but actually showed up for the tab itself.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/281308458596344

I was also warned (and flagged) for posting about this on stack overflow this morning, so just letting you know, this should be posted on the Facebook bug pages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a missing script. The "Choose File" input is meant to upload the image onchange:

```
<input type="file" name="image_upload" onchange="DevelopersImageUploader.submitToIframe(); return false;">
```

however the DevelopersImageUploader object is not available as shown by the console message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DevelopersImageUploader is not defined
(anonymous function)/apps/230113777067870/summary/:1
onchange
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent problem.  Not only for iFrame Tab but also for other kind off application.  The uploader was working last week (2012-01-20).